# My futures composition "seems to have slain the compiler"

Tags: scala

I was playing with side-effects in futures and got the most bizarre stack trace I've ever seen from the Scala compiler (2.11.1). Does anyone know what could be going on here?

```
scala> import scala.concurrent._; import ExecutionContext.Implicits._
scala> var sum = 0; Future{Thread.sleep(1000); sum += 23} andThen Future{Thread.sleep(1000); sum += 7}

java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
  Future({
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  sum.<$plus$eq: error>(7)
})
     while compiling: <console>
        during phase: superaccessors
     library version: version 2.11.1
    compiler version: version 2.11.1
  reconstructed args: 

  last tree to typer: This(object $iw)
       tree position: line 15 of <console>
            tree tpe: $line29.$read.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.type
              symbol: object $iw
   symbol definition: class $iw extends AnyRef (a ModuleClassSymbol)
      symbol package: $line29
       symbol owners: object $iw -> object $iw -> object $iw -> object $iw ->    object $iw -> object $iw -> object $read
           call site: object $iw in package $line29

<Cannot read source file>
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer.transform(SuperAcc essors.scala:320)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer$$anonfun$transform Args$1.apply(SuperAccessors.scala:86)
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.SuperAccessors$SuperAccTransformer$$anonfun$transformArgs$1.apply(SuperAccessors.scala:83)
    at scala.reflect.internal.TreeInfo$$anonfun$mapMethodParamsAndArgs$1.apply(TreeInfo.scala:231)
    at scala.reflect.internal.TreeInfo$$anonfun$mapMethodParamsAndArgs$1.apply(TreeInfo.scala:231)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.Collections$class.foreach2(Collections.scala:218)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.foreach2(SymbolTable.scala:16)
...
That entry seems to have slain the compiler.  Shall I replay
your session? I can re-run each line except the last one.
[y/n]
Abandoning crashed session.
```

You can view the full stack trace here: http://pastebin.com/Q85CQqDh

Comment: It's been pretty easy to slay the compiler in the REPL throughout 2.11's history. I know some similar bugs have been fixed in recent releases, but I was just able to reproduce this in 2.11.6 and it doesn't seem to be covered by any of the [known issues](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9200?jql=project%20%3D%20SI%20AND%20status%3Dopen%20AND%20affectedVersion%20%3D%20%22Scala%202.11.6%22%20and%20fixVersion%20%3E%3D%20%22Scala%202.11.6%22%20ORDER%20BY%20component%20ASC%2C%20priority%20DESC), so who knows.